# Printing complex Go structs in GDB

Tags: gdb, go

I need some help in using GDB + Python extensions for Go.

The struct LogQuery I am trying to look into is composed as follows:

```
   LogQuery (struct)
     CommonCmd (struct)
         Context (struct)
            out
            Globs
         flagHelp
         ...
      flagLog
      ...


Breakpoint 3, acme/subcmds.CmdObj (context=..., cmdName="log_query", noname=
    void) at /nobackup/git/goacme/src/acme/subcmds/cmder.go:32
32   cmd = NewLogQuery(context) //debugger
(gdb) s
acme/subcmds.NewLogQuery (context=..., noname=void)
    at /nobackup/git/goacme/src/acme/subcmds/log_query.go:29
29  func NewLogQuery(context context.Context) LogQuery {
(gdb) n
30   obj := LogQuery{NewCommonCmd(context), "", "", "", "", 0, "", ""}
(gdb) 
31   return obj
```

1 - printing the object (obj) inside the constructor works. But how do I see 'obj.Globs'?

```
(gdb) p obj
$8 = {acme/subcmds.CommonCmd = {acme/context.Context = {out = 0, Globs = 
    0xf840050140}, FlagArgs = "", flagDebug = "", flagHelp = false, 
    flagOutput = "", flagVerbose = false, CmdName = "", debug = 0x0}, 
  flagColl = "", flagData = "", flagDb = "", flagHost = "", flagLimit = 0, 
  flagLog = "", flagQuery = ""}
```

Returning to the caller

```
(gdb) n
acme/subcmds.CmdObj (context=..., cmdName="log_query", noname=void)
    at /nobackup/git/goacme/src/acme/subcmds/cmder.go:40
40   if cmdName == "acme" {
```

Here I see the type of the object, but can't seem to be able the see anything in it

```
(gdb) p cmd
$9 = "(subcmds.LogQuery)0xf840052b60"

(gdb) p $dtype(cmd)
$2 = (struct cmds.Add *) 0xf840034210

(gdb) p cmd->Globs
A syntax error in expression, near `>Globs'.

(gdb) p cmd.Globs
There is no member named Globs.
```

Comment: How, precisely, do we reproduce your problem?

Comment: did you load the go/src/pkg/runtime/runtime-gdb.py inside gdb?